# Which ANSI standard is Joel referring to?

Tags: character-encoding, standards

I was rereading Joel Spolsky's classic blog post [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and noticed this passage:

> Eventually this OEM free-for-all got codified in **the ANSI standard** *(emphasis mine).* In the ANSI standard, everybody agreed on what to do below 128, which was pretty much the same as ASCII, but there were lots of different ways to handle the characters from 128 and on up, depending on where you lived. These different systems were called [code pages.](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/codepages.html#msftdos)

Which ANSI standard is this text referring to? To be sure, the American National Standards Institute has published a number of standards (after all, that's what they actually *do),* but I have been unable to figure out which one.

My closest guess as to what this might allude to is that this actually talks about ISO-8859, and perhaps this document began life as an American standard before being adopted as an international standard; but then that doesn't make sense in the context of standardizing "code pages" and "OEM" character sets.

[Wikipedia's *Code page* article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) mentions an IBM standard, and notes that IANA maintains a registry of code page mappings, but obviously, neither of them is ANSI.

My understanding is that ANSI has not standardized any modern 8-bit character set, and that "ANSI" in this context generally refers to Microsoft's now-abandoned confused terminology (where "ANSI" was at a time apparently used to mean something like the currently selected code page).

Is there a standard I am overlooking? Or is there simply just (gasp) an error on Joel's blog?

Comment: Related on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the links, though I am well aware of the technical nomenclature in this area. Do you think I should clarify this in my question?

Comment: And you'll notice that the second link mainly just says that this is not well-defined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences#comment49756855_700221 alleges that Microsoft submitted a proposal to ANSI, but that it was rejected. But surely Joel should have known that?

Comment: Some nice history at https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-ansi-format

Comment: Uh, that's really vague, and for a page titled "What Is ANSI Format?" remarkably absent of any actual explanation. It does seem to suggest the same story; that Microsoft wanted their code pages (here, specifically 1252) to be officially standardized, but this didn't happen.

Comment: [Windows code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_code_pages) are all based on [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) which was completed in 1992. As Spolsky's blog dates from 2003, this is a lack in his post. I remark that his post is not claimed to be comprehensive, but rather a minimum.

Comment: This sounds to me like that excerpt is simply saying "**below 128 is just ascii**" whereas "**above 128 depends on system locale**". Is the system where it's interpreted German, English-US, English-UK, Chinese, and so forth.... So the mapping per ANSI standards for above 128 depends on the region you are in or the locale the system which is interpreting is using. The standards are set per system locale defined and that should be the standard but what that is depends on the local.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT It very specifically says "the ANSI standard" codifies this. Is that incorrect? If not, which ANSI standard?

Comment: @tripleee ... I believe it's this or something along these line: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers. I think this is also worth a read: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages but these seem to be more for legacy support and moving forward things should use unicode instead. So the standard will depend on the system you are using e.g. Windows, Mac, etc. and the locale and language such systems are configured to use. This is at least my interpretation from some of these readings.

Comment: This seems to have a comprehensive list as well across different platforms perhaps https://www.aivosto.com/articles/charsets-codepages.html.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to understand code pages better. This is a question about how they are related to a supposed ANSI standard. The second Microsoft page contains an info box which again reinforces the story that Microsoft wanted codepage 1252 to be ratified by ANSI, but that this didn't happen (though according to this page it's what eventually led to ISO-8859-1). If you can find actual information about this from a credible source (perhaps even Microsoft?) that would be a useful answer and definitely better than the single answer so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without input from Joel, we can't know for sure, but based on the other answer attempts here and the flaws I perceive with them, let me submit what I consider an obvious and simple speculation:

**There is no actual ANSI standard here, and Joel is glossing things over.**

What exactly is being summarized and possibly mixed up here is definitely less certain, but my guess would be that he is talking about the development of Windows code pages, which for a time were called "ANSI code pages" by Microsoft, even though there never was any tangible connection to the American National Standards Institute, possibly outside of an ultimately unsuccessful effort to standardize Windows code page 1252 as an "extended ASCII" with various accented characters for some Western European languages and symbols useful for typesetting and simple mathematical expressions. According to some sources, this is what ultimately resulted in [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and eventually the larger family of [ISO 8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) standards for 8-bit character sets for various regions (see also [ECMA-94](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-094.htm)).

For the record, the ASA and then [ANSI Committee X3](http://www.worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n84-18163/) was responsible for the ASCII standard (ASA X3.4, then ANSI X3.4, then ISO 646) as well as the X3.64 standard for ASCII screen control sequences for display terminals. Notable publications by this committee in the late 1980s include a proposal for the C language and something called "extended Pascal" as well as the SCSI hardware interface, but I could find nothing related to character sets from this period.

Comment: I wouldn't say that Spolsky is ignorant about the question or that he didn't do any research before writing his article, as after all we are talking about a very capable person. I would go for a badly-written sentence that glossed over several subjects, treating an ANSI standard and what followed in one too-short sentence. But I wouldn't go for no standard at all, since in reality such a standard did exist and did start everything rolling - ASCII. I don't accept your argument that it was too long ago to be included, since he is giving here a *historical* overview.

Comment: This is Community Wiki so you are encouraged to tweak the wording. But thanks for your feedback; I toned down the language a bit.

Comment: Better but still the same : "There is no ANSI standard" is the same as saying that Spolsky is talking nonsense. His paragraph is badly-written and hard to understand, but with my respect for the person in question I would try to make some sense of it instead of rejecting it.

Comment: Mistakes happen even to experienced writers and I don't think it's out of line to at least raise the possibility that this is actually the explanation. I must have read the blog post something like 50 times over the years without noticing this discrepancy.

Comment: Glossing over several decades of development in one sentence certainly makes for an unclear sentence, but that's what I would read into it.

Comment: Basically our two answers only differ on whether there was or there wasn't an ANSI standard. If there was, then my answer is the one. If there wasn't, then your answer is certainly a possibility. It's your post, so your choice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a puzzle, so let's assemble all the known facts.
We are looking for:

- An ANSI standard
- About character sets
- Which specified the first 128 code-points
- And was the basis for code pages and all following standards for character sets.

The result for me is only one - the
[ASCII Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).
I believe this was the first standard by ANSI to specify the first 128 code-points,
and actually also the last.

Although ASCII evolved in details later on, its main development started
in 1963. This standard was developed by the American branch
of the International Organization for Standardization (ISO), which is ANSI.
Because this standard omitted reference to non-American characters, and as the
code-pages that followed and attempted to answer that question
were a real disorganized mess, being able to agree only on the
ASCII part, the work of standardization
was taken up by the international organization of ISO itself.

Historically speaking, the
[ISO/IEC 8859 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)
arrived between ASCII and the code-pages, but this was not an ANSI standard,
elaborated rather by the ISO.

"ANSI code pages" was a misnomer for
[Windows code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) that were
were created by Microsoft and not by ANSI.
One variant was the code page of
[Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252),
which later came to be known as
[ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

The actual history of character sets is pretty convoluted,
and extensive detective work would be
required to establish time-tables, cross-influences, and resulting de facto standards
or definitions. But it all was started by ASCII, which created a basis for all
future evolution culminating in Unicode and UTF-8.

Comment: But this cannot be the ANSI standard which Joel Spolsky refers to in the quotation. ASCII was codified in the early 1960s and the quoted section is specifically about the "tower of Babel" situation which emerged over the following decades as a myriad of incompatible 8-bit "extensions" of the 7-bit ASCII standard proliferated.

Comment: Also, you first say code pages happened before ISO 8859, but then say the standard emerged from code pages. (The latter is correct, I believe. Though ISO 8859-1 is not in fact exactly identical to Windows code page 1252.)

Comment: Comment 1: ASCII was in development for many years, so Spolsky might be referring to ASCII and the whole process that it started, including ANSI & ISO committees and sub-committees, which you rightly call "tower of Babel". If you look at its [History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#History), it was still in development in 1986. 2: I said that the referred standard happened before the code pages, not the opposite. I ask this: Can you think of any other ANSI standard that fulfills the listed requirements and had that kind of impact? I can't.

Comment: The reason I cannot find a relevant ANSI standard is the very reason I am posting my question. I can't make sense of the quoted passage, or the entire blog post, with the information in this answer; I simply don't believe it is correct. The latest amendments to ANSI X.3.4 are definitely a red herring; even though the latest revision was passed in 1986, ASCII has effectively been fixed since the 1960s.

Comment: I believe in Occam's Razor and the simplest explanation. Besides, I have looked at all ANSI standards and semi-standards relating to character sets, and there is no other good candidate that I could find. Spolsky would certainly not refer to some obscure committee report as being that important.

Comment: But if he meant ASCII, how do you explain the fragment *"In the ANSI standard, everybody agreed on what to do below 128, which was pretty much the same as ASCII"?* If he actually meant ASCII, it would be very odd to say it was "pretty much the same as ASCII".

Comment: I would understand this as: Below 128, everybody did pretty much the same as ASCII. The word "everybody" implies "multiple", and this in my opinion can only refer to the multiple code-pages. The "pretty much" part instead of "identical" refers to some binary codes below 128 that were left unspecified and used differently on various code pages.

Answer (score -1):

According to [their wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) the C0 and C1 control characters are defined in ANSI x3.4.

These include the escape sequences for extended text formatting which are used by [ISO 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022) and [ISO 8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) to allow multi byte international character sets.

For example ESC $ @ and ESC $ B switch to different Japanese 2-byte encodings while ESC ( B switches back to US-ASCII.  These might be ISO (or ECMA) standards but they use the ANSI control codes, so this is probably a partial misnomer.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not seem to attempt to answer my actual question at all.

Comment: My guess is that their isn't one.  That there are actually SEVERAL non-ANSI standards by various foreign standards bodies that use the ANSI defined control code sets (ANSI x3.4) for escape sequences to invoke them.

Answer (score -4):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#History

According to this list, the first ANSI standard defining ASCII was ANSI X3.4-1977.